# How to reload chrome://inspector android webview devtools

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-chrome

I can debug android webview with

desktop chrome chrome://inspect > click my app "inspect" > open devtools

but in android studio, I rebuild and reinstall app, **above devtools** show:

[image]

when i click 'reconnect devtools', devtools show blank

**so how to reload remote debug devtools**